# Is it permissible to scrape Facebook through the Graph API?

Tags: facebook

Can I use the Graph API to scrape Facebook? And, if so what are the terms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can scrape Facebook according to [these terms](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php?hc_location=ufi). After you agree to those terms, you must submit [this agreement](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos.php)